# Human foibles "more generally"

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

> In addition to war and politics,
>   Aristophanes also ridiculed characteristics of Athenians
>   themselves and human foibles **more generally**. In The
>   Wasps, he poked fun at Athenians’ obsession with
>   unnecessary lawsuits. Bdelycleon, driven to despair by
>   his father Philocleon’s compulsive attachment to jury
>   duty, tries to keep the old man from the law courts by
>   allowing him to conduct a trial of two dogs, one of which
>   is called Cleon.

In this context I get confused whether the meaning of " more generally" is: widely (including every people) or it means: not including details?

Source: Gale Contextual Encyclopedia Of World Literature

Answer (score 1):

**Particularly** the Athenians
**More generally** all humans.

The group of humans is wider and more general than just the Athenians.  This is all that the expression "more generally" means in this context

Comment: Lots of thanks. So it means that he has considered all human's foibles not just Athenians' foibels.

Comment: He has not only considered them, but also ridiculed them!